# Fours boxes equally separated, but one doesn`t listen

Tags: css, block

Here is a fiddle of the problem. http://www.jsfiddle.net/PL6KX/
I do not know where the problem is. Would appreciate help.
Thanks.

I want to center everything proportionally from the edges. Horizontal center.

HTML:

```
<div id="firstleft-box"></div>
<div id="secondleft-box"></div>
<div id="firstright-box"></div>
<div id="secondright-box"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#firstleft-box {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 20%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#secondleft-box {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 40%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#firstright-box {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 60%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#secondright-box {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 80%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I want to center everything proportionally from the edges.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me?  What exactly is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: They're all equally separated.

Comment: then I would suggest some wrapper around your divs and center it with margin: 0px auto;

Comment: I want them to be equally separated from the "walls" as well. Cause shouldnt they 20% 40% 60% 80%.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PL6KX/3/

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of why your code is not producing the output that you are expecting.  I have also provided a solution that is safer for you to use.  Using position:absolute can be dangerous for layout design as it is interpreted differently based on screen size.

Comment: So what is more recommended, floating, relative, what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` to get divs next to each other, `margin` to make space between them and then wrap one div around them and center it with `margin: 0px auto;` your approach is too complicated

Comment: Am I doing it somewhat complex?

Comment: No, you are just doing it wrong :-) there is no need to use percentage in this case

Comment: Just look at fiddle that Explosion Pills posted in comments, its very similar to my proposal and it works

Answer (score 0):

See the following JS Fiddle for a demonstration on why your code is not producing the output you are expecting.

http://jsfiddle.net/PL6KX/2/

Basically, you are aligning the left side of each box at 20, 40, 60, 80 etc.  You are assuming that it would align the center of your boxes.  What I have done in the above fiddle is to create 5 boxes 20% wide so that the points where they meet and touch each other represent 20%, 40%, 60% and 80%.  As you can see your boxes at the top are aligning their left edge to those percentages.

What you need: (third set of boxes in the fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/PL6KX/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div id="new-box"></div>
<div id="new-box"></div>
<div id="new-box"></div>
<div id="new-box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#new-box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```